# C# formatting output of methods from a class and no data is displayed now

Tags: c#, string, methods, formatting

So I wanted to format this text so it was being padded and was all nice and square not dependant on the length of different address sizes or names. However now that its in this format...nothing shows up in regard to the actuall variables and values.

Before I did

```
  Console.WriteLine(emp[i].GetEmpName());
```

and it worked fine, it displayed the string stored in that method. now I am unsure where the disconnect is but it now is displaying a blank value such as

```
Employee Name:
EmployeeAddress:
```

so forth.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            string eNum = "Employee Number: ";
            string eName = "Emplyee Name: ";
            string eAddress = "Employee Address: ";


            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.Write("|");
            Console.Write(eNum.PadRight(30), emp[i].GetEmpNum());
            Console.Write("|\n");

            Console.Write("|");
            Console.Write(eName.PadRight(30), emp[i].GetEmpName());
            Console.Write("|\n");

            Console.Write("|");
            Console.Write(eAddress.PadRight(30), emp[i].GetEmpAddress());
            Console.Write("|\n");
            //Console.Write();
            //Console.Write();
            Console.Write("|");
            Console.Write("Net Pay: {0:f2}", emp[i].CalcSalary());
            Console.WriteLine("\n------------------------------------------------------ ------------------\n\n");
        }
```

The rest of the code is here if you want to see it. Again it works as long as you dont format the output.

Where did I go so horribly wrong?!?!

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace Proj10
{
class Program
{
    const int ARRAY_TWO = 2;

    static void Main()
    {
        int count = 0;

        Employee[] emp = new Employee[10];

        string environment = System.Environment.GetFolderPath
        (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\";

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a file name in My Documents: ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        string path = environment + input;

        StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(path);


        do
        {

            if (myFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                break;
            }
            int num = int.Parse(myFile.ReadLine());
            string name = myFile.ReadLine();
            string address = myFile.ReadLine();
            string hourNworked = myFile.ReadLine();
            double[] values = new double[ARRAY_TWO];
            sort(hourNworked, ref values);

            emp[count] = new Employee();
            emp[count].SetEmpNum(num);
            emp[count].SetEmpName(name);
            emp[count].SetEmpAddress(address);
            emp[count].SetEmpHrlyPay(values[0]);
            emp[count].SetEmpHrsWrked(values[1]);



            //while count < 10 && !myfile.EOF();

            //print loop using count 
            //emp[0].GetEmpNum();
            //emp[0].CalcSalary();

            /*Integer[] number = new Integer[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                number[i] = new Integer(i);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                Console.WriteLine(number[i].GetValue());
            */

            count++;


        } while (count < 10);

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nAuthor: Daniel Demers");
        Console.WriteLine("CS 1400 X01\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            string eNum = "Employee Number: ";
            string eName = "Emplyee Name: ";
            string eAddress = "Employee Address: ";


            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.Write("|");
            Console.Write(eNum.PadRight(30), emp[i].GetEmpNum());
            Console.Write("|\n");

            Console.Write("|");
            Console.Write(eName.PadRight(30), emp[i].GetEmpName());
            Console.Write("|\n");

            Console.Write("|");
            Console.Write(eAddress.PadRight(30), emp[i].GetEmpAddress());
            Console.Write("|\n");
            //Console.Write();
            //Console.Write();
            Console.Write("|");
            Console.Write("Net Pay: {0:f2}", emp[i].CalcSalary());
            Console.WriteLine("\n------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void sort(string hourNworked, ref double[] values)
    {
        char[] rules = { ' ' };
        string[] splitArray = hourNworked.Split(rules);
        values[0] = double.Parse(splitArray[0]);
        values[1] = double.Parse(splitArray[1]);
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        private int empNum;
        private string name;
        private string address;
        private double hrlyPay;
        private double hrsWrkd;
        private double GROSS;
        private double overTime;
        private double overTimePay;
        private double overTimeHours;
        private double NET;
        private double regTime;
        private double fTaxAmount;
        private double sTaxAmount;

        private const double FED_TAX = .20;
        private const double STATE_TAX = .075;
        private const double OT_MULTIPLYER = 1.5;
        private const int FORTY_HOURS = 40;


        public Employee()
        {
            empNum = 0;
        }

        public void SetEmpNum(int n)
        {
            empNum = n;
        }

        public int GetEmpNum()
        {
            return empNum;
        }
        public void SetEmpName(string n)
        {
            name = n;
        }
        public string GetEmpName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        public void SetEmpAddress(string a)
        {
            address = a;
        }
        public string GetEmpAddress()
        {
            return address;
        }
        public void SetEmpHrlyPay(double h)
        {
            hrlyPay = h;
        }
        public double GetEmpHrlyPay()
        {
            return hrlyPay;
        }
        public void SetEmpHrsWrked(double w)
        {
            hrsWrkd = w;
        }
        public double GetEmpHrsWrkd()
        {
            return hrsWrkd;
        }
        public double CalcSalary()
        {
            if (hrsWrkd > 40)
            {
                overTimeHours = hrsWrkd - FORTY_HOURS;
                overTimePay = hrlyPay * OT_MULTIPLYER;
                overTime = overTimePay * overTimeHours;
                regTime = (hrsWrkd - overTimeHours) * hrlyPay;
                GROSS = overTime + regTime;

                fTaxAmount = (regTime + overTime) * FED_TAX;
                sTaxAmount = (regTime + overTime) * STATE_TAX;

                NET = GROSS - (fTaxAmount + sTaxAmount);

                return NET;
            }
            else
            {
                regTime = hrlyPay * hrsWrkd;
                fTaxAmount = regTime * FED_TAX;
                sTaxAmount = regTime * STATE_TAX;

                NET = regTime - (fTaxAmount + sTaxAmount);

                return NET;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Console.Write` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xdyw6yk.aspx) you are using takes a format string and an object. Since your first argument does not contain any placeholders, the second argument is not used.

Try this instead:

```
Console.WriteLine("|{0,-30}{1,-20}|", eNum, emp[i].GetEmpNum());
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/rERJO)